# curl fails with timeout on gitlab-ci runner

Tags: docker, curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a simple ci which is supposed to build a docker image and trigger the deployment via a stage url.

Therefore i use a simple curl request  `curl -X POST $STAGE_URL`

The pipeline works on shared runners but on my own runner it fails with after 2:45 min with `curl: (28) Failed to connect to www.someurl.com port 443: Operation timed out`

My `config.toml` looks like this

```
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "scalangular-runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "abcdefghijklm"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    cach_dir = "cache"
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does your runner have any firewall rules set up? Are you able to reach e.g `curl google.com` from you runner?

Comment: i tryed it and it works  ```$ curl -X POST www.google.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>```

As far as i know there are no firewall rules.

Comment: Does `www.someurl.com` resolve to private IP address or the public one? If you are able to `ssh` into runner and troubleshoot networking from there, that would be ideal. The message from curl: `Failed to connect: operation timed out` normally means that your machine (runner in this case) was unable to reach the destination host. Some tools to try: `ping` or `traceroute` to make sure there is route to the destination host; `telnet` or `nc` to make sure you are able to establish TCP connection to `www.someurl.com` on port `443`.

Comment: Does `www.someurl.com` resolve to private IP address or the public one? If you are able to `ssh` into runner and troubleshoot networking from there, that would be ideal. The message from curl: `Failed to connect: operation timed out` normally means that your machine (runner in this case) was unable to reach the destination host. Some tools to try: `ping` or `traceroute` to make sure there is route to the destination host; `telnet` or `nc` to make sure you are able to establish TCP connection to `www.someurl.com` on port `443`.

Comment: Did you find solutions for that